# Sum over certain indices not working

Tags: summation

Define a function $h$ by

```
h[m_,n_]:=2^n Binomial[m,Ceiling[m/2]]Binomial[n,Ceiling[n/2]]Ceiling[m/2]Ceiling[n/2](m-1)b^(m+n)/((m+n)m!n!)
```

I am trying to evaluate

```
Sum[If[EvenQ[m+n],h[m,n],0],{m,1,Infinity},{n,1,Infinity}]
```

that is, sum of $h$ over indices $(m, n)$ with $m+n$ even. But my notebook gives me the answer $0$. I'd like to know the expression of the sum in terms of $b$. Could you please help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This problem is quite common here.`EvenQ` is a programmatic thing that has to return `True` or `False`. It gets evaluated `False` before the `Sum` which causes the sum to be zero. Consider this simpler sum: `Sum[If[EvenQ[x], 1/x^2, 0], {x, 1, \[Infinity]}]` which gives zero. Instead of using `If[EvenQ[x],f[x],0]` you could use `(1 - Mod[x, 2])*f[x]` instead. In my example `Sum[(1 - Mod[x, 2])*1/x^2, {x, 1, Infinity}]` evaluates to Pi^2/24 which is correct, so try removing the whole `If` and do `Sum[(1 - Mod[m+n, 2])*h[m,n],{m,1,Infinity},{n,1,Infinity}]`.

Comment: ^ the sum will take a long time to compute - I still haven't got a result. There might not even be a closed form. If you sum over a finite range it works as expected however: `Sum[(1 - Mod[m + n, 2]) h[m, n], {m, 1, 3}, {n, 1, 3}]` gives $2 b^4 + 8 b^6/3$